# How to send data to server in tab base forms

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

Hi I have Designed tabs in bootstrap with two set of form fields, the first set of form fields is person data form fields in one div the second set form fields is Address data form fields in another div
How to avoid filling second set of form fields without filling first set of form fields meant in first tab if user clicks on next button it should validate using bootstrap validation

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpo89f88/1/

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->


<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <div class="card">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home"
                            aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Person Data</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile"
                            aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Address Data</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                PersonFirstName <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                    name="PersonFirstName">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                PersonLastName <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                    name="PersonLastName">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                Address 1 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addr1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                Address 2 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addr2">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not so complete validation, here is the snippet to validate first tab before entering new tab. Code is documented with comments. Hope this helps.

```js
var form = document.forms[0]; //reading the form from dom
function isFirstFormValid(){
  return form.PersonFirstName.value !== "" && form.PersonLastName.value !== "";
  //you can write more validation rules here
}
$("#next-submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (isFirstFormValid()) {
    $('a[href="#profile"]').tab('show'); //if first form is valid
  }else{
    alert("All fields required..!"); //give your own message
  }
});

//In the same way check for last submit button which submits form if everything okay. I.e isSecondFormValid()

$("form").submit(function(e) {
  if(isFirstFormValid()){ //also check for second form
  console.log("ready to submit");
  }else{
    alert("Validation Failed");
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  border-width: 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  border: none;
  color: #666;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  border: none;
  color: #4285F4 !important;
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a::after {
  content: "";
  background: #4285F4;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -1px;
  transition: all 250ms ease 0s;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a::after,
.nav-tabs>li:hover>a::after {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.tab-nav>li>a::after {
  background: #21527d none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab-pane {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.tab-content {
  padding: 20px
}

.card {
  background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

body {
  background: #EDECEC;
  padding: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form name="myForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <div class="card">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Person Data</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Address Data</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
              <div class="form-group">
                PersonFirstName <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="PersonFirstName">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                PersonLastName <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="PersonLastName">
              </div>
              <button id="next-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
              <div class="form-group">
                Address 1 <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="addr1">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                Address 2 <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="addr2">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" id="next-submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```